# Given a linear mapping and a matrix prove that two products are equal.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L : R^n \to R^n$ be a linear mapping with standard matrix $A = [L]$, and let $B = [b_1,...,b_n]$ be an $nxn$ matrix with $rank(B) = n$. Given that $C ={b_1,...,b_n}$ is a basis for $R^n$.

Prove that $B[[A(b_1)]_C,....,[A(b_n)]_C] =AB$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notation is truly horrendous, but I suppose that for $v\in\Bbb R^n$ the notation $v_C$ means the column formed of the coordinates of $v$ with respect to $C$. Those are obtained by multiplying $v$ to the left by the inverse $B^{-1}$ of the matrix whose columns hold the coordinates (in the standard basis) of the vectors $b_j$ of the basis $C$. Then you are computing
$$
  B[B^{-1}A(b_1)~\ldots~B^{-1}A(b_n)]
 =[A(b_1)~\ldots~A(b_n)]=AB.
$$
But maybe the goal of the exercise was to deduce the fact that the coordinates with respect to $C$ are given by multiplying by $B^{-1}$ in the first place (in which case my explanation is not very helpful)? In that case I would humbly suggest that there are better ways to explain that by such a convoluted exercice.

Comment: +1 for a great answer, and for ''your notation is truly horrendous". :)

Comment: I believe it is the second option and thank you for the helpful response.